# dateutil.parser strange result when parsing date in the format "%Y:%m:%d"

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, python-dateutil

I love `dateutil.parser` and use it often so I don't have to worry about inconsistent datetime formats and in most cases it has been very reliable for me.

But then today I've spent an hour debugging trying to understand why dates I'm populating in the database are all from 2022. The date format is: `2009:05:03 08:12:37` as stored in photo metadata and extracted using `exif` package.

It feels like it should be a reasonably straightforward format to parse but this is what I get with `dateutil` and `datetime` modules, respectively:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime as dt

date_string = '2009:05:03 08:12:37'

wrong = parse(date_string, fuzzy=True)
correct = dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")

print(wrong)
print(correct)

Out:
2022-07-25 08:12:37
2009-05-03 08:12:37
```

And both the normal and fuzzy parsing give the same result. And it's strange, I don't even understand how it could come up with this exact result.

It looks it tried to parse and did the time successfully but failed to parse date and put the current date by default.This feels like a very dangerous behaviour. It should raise an exception.

Comment: My guess is it's picking up the date portion as a time then over-writing that with the time portion. Since it didn't catch the date, it used today's date.

Comment: @Ouroborus, yeah I guess this is the case. As I said in the updated post, I feel like it's a very dangerous behaviour. It should raise exception if it failed to parse date successfully, not just put today's date by default.

Comment: @pavel could you provide the exact value of `im['datetime']` ? As I do not have the `Photo/DSC_1270.JPG` file I can't reproduce and try to debug the issue.

Comment: @Lenormju, I had it in the post in text. I'll add it to the code block instead: `2009:05:03 08:12:37`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) parameter `default` says :

> The default datetime object, if this is a datetime object and not `None`, elements specified in `timestr` replace elements in the default object.

Which is very clear in [the `parser.parse()` code on Github](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/da9ecd07a257cb5d1c7bfa08459b1ccfcabe6d23/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L637) :

```py
        if default is None:
            default = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0,
                                                      second=0, microsecond=0)
```

But the behavior being documented does not make it obvious, I agree with you that the result was surprising.

As for why it failed, later it will [`_timelex.split(timestr)`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/da9ecd07a257cb5d1c7bfa08459b1ccfcabe6d23/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L719) which ultimately calls [`_timelex.get_token()`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/da9ecd07a257cb5d1c7bfa08459b1ccfcabe6d23/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L77). It is a state machine implemented in pure Python to parse time strings, and it correctly returns the tokens `['2009', ':', '05', ':', '03', ' ', '08', ':', '12', ':', '37']`.
But then `_parse()` iterates on them tries to interpret them, so it calls [`_parse_numeric_token()`](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/da9ecd07a257cb5d1c7bfa08459b1ccfcabe6d23/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L875) on it. This function tries to match the tokens with specific cases. There are somes cases in which "ymd" (year/month/day) get set (what you would like) :

- `YYMMDD` (first token without any space nor dot (`.`))
- `YYYYMMDD[HHMM[ss]]` (first token without space, including time)
- token followed by one of `-/.`
- last token or followed by any of  `.,;-/'` (or any word of `at/on/and/ad/m/t/of/st/nd/rd/th`)
- token could be a day

But instead it matches the case "followed by `:`" which then gets interpreted as `HH:MM:SS` into `_result(hour=2009, minute=5, second=3, microsecond=0)`. Which consumes the 5 first tokens (the whole expected YMD). After that, it skips the whitespace, goes back into `_parse_numeric_token()`, matches the exact same case and overwites the HMS into `_result(hour=8, minute=12, second=37, microsecond=0)`.
It has not found any YMD, so there is nothing done by `ymd.resolve_ymd()`.

Back upto `parse()` (without the leading underscore), it [builds a naive](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/da9ecd07a257cb5d1c7bfa08459b1ccfcabe6d23/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L1235) datetime (no timezone) by replacing `parse()` result fields into the `default`, which ends up being the final result.

I think it may be cause for opening an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues) but I fear it may be considered "Won't fix" because the data you provided is strange : time-parts are usually delimited by colons while date-parts are (basically) never delimited by them (cf [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). I had never saw this datetime format before.

I recommend instead that either you fix the code that is producing this malformed data, or that you add something like `if malformed := re.match("(\d)+:(\d+):(\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+)", date_string): date_string = f"{malformed.group(0)}-{malformed.group(1)}-{malformed.group(2)} {malformed.group(3)}"`
to reformat the data in a format expected by the dateutil parser.

---

About [`fuzzy`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse)  :

> Whether to allow fuzzy parsing, allowing for string like “Today is January 1, 2047 at 8:21:00AM”.

What it actually does is in the `_parse()` function, where it tries to find a match for the current token, if nothing matches, it will not raise a `ValueError` if `fuzzy`. So for any valid non-fuzzy input, the fuzzy result will be the same.
In this case, it changes nothing (but it may be useful for other date_strings you receive, I can't tell).

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed and well-investigated answer.